# user enters multiple strings and then all strings displayed when stopped

Tags: java, string, while-loop

The program is supposed to allow the user to enter words until "xxx" is entered, then the program ends. It must display every word that the user entered when the program ends.

Example...

User enters:

- I
- like
- pie
- xxx

Displays: I like pie

```
    String str;
    do
    { 
         str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter a word")!;
    }
    while (str.equalsIgnoreCase  ("xxx"));
    System.out.println (str);
```

All it displays is "xxx"

How do I fix this?

Comment: you are almost there, where do you have an issue with??

Comment: I'm not sure how to store each string individually

Comment: individually?? then use a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this :

```
String str = ""; //work to read
String result = ""; //final resul
do {
    str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a word");
    if (!str.equals("xxx")) {//if word != xxx then you can add it else escape it
        result += str + " ";
    }

} while (!str.equalsIgnoreCase("xxx"));

System.out.println(result);
```

**Output**

```
I like pie
```

Comment: maybe `if () {...} else {break;}` would be better?

Comment: why @ScaryWombat why you need the break, it will break after the `str.equalsIgnoreCase("xxx")` so the `else{ break; }` is not important in this case i'm wrong?

Comment: Nah, it is not important - you are right. But if the specs change and you have to end on the String `endNow`, you need to change code in two places

Answer (score 0):

You want to loop until`Str` is **not** `xxx`

```
String str;
final String endWord = "xxx";
do
{ 
     str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter a word!");
     System.out.println (str);
}
while (!str.equalsIgnoreCase  (endWord));
```

I would consider adding the words to an ArrayList and then printing them afterwards

e.g.

```
      ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList<>();
      String str;
      final String endWord = "xxx";
      do
      { 
           str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter a word!");
           list.add (str);
      }
      while (!str.equalsIgnoreCase  (endWord));

      for (String word : list) {
          if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(endWord)) break;
          System.out.println(word);
      }
```

Comment: how would I do that?